# Cannot build .apk in visual studio c# android

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

So, i'm new in visual studio, and i want to learn how to make android application using c# in vs,but when i compile hello world project to .apk, Package output always show me this error:

`No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2045-07-29) or after any future revocation date.`

I have tried to find the solution for this problem but i didn't get anything from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems related to a Java version, have you tried upgrading your Xamarin plugin ?

this guy has fixed it by adding `-tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com` into his .csproj

http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2015/06/getting-rid-of-no-tsa-or-tsacert-is.html

and here's how to create signing keys

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/